# Проблема со стилем DataGridRow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Пишу стиль, в зависимости от значения в столбике цвет строки должен меняться. Стиль работает, но появилась проблема: выбранная строка не отображается. Как это можно решить?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RecordVms }">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="InProgress">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

На скрине сейчас выбрана строка 3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно взять родной стиль `DataGridRow` и добавить нужные пару строчек.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyleStateGreen" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit" Value="{Binding SelectionUnit, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="2,0" ToolTip="{Binding DataContext.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path Data="M31.630585,39.233818L56.261485,14.603018C56.879785,13.984618,57.882285,13.984618,58.500685,14.603018L83.131485,39.233818C83.749885,39.852218,83.749885,40.854718,83.131485,41.473018L58.500685,66.103918C57.882385,66.722218,56.879785,66.722218,56.261485,66.103918L31.630585,41.473018C31.012285,40.854718,31.012285,39.852218,31.630585,39.233818z" Fill="{DynamicResource ControlsValidationBrush}" Height="20" Stretch="Uniform" Width="20"/>
                        <Path Data="M53.781741,31.196677C51.544017,31.196677 49.719241,33.021453 49.719241,35.259177 49.719241,37.496901 51.544017,39.321677 53.781741,39.321677 56.019465,39.321677 57.844241,37.496901 57.844241,35.259177 57.844241,33.021453 56.019465,31.196677 53.781741,31.196677z M49.687991,9.821677L49.719241,10.352927 50.937991,29.821677 56.625491,29.821677 57.875491,9.821677 49.687991,9.821677z" Fill="{DynamicResource ValidationTextBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!--мой триггер-->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="InProgress">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <!---->
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="FullRow"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.HighlightBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.HighlightBrush}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="FullRow"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Selector.IsSelectionActive), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="FullRow"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.MouseOverHighlightBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.MouseOverHighlightBrush}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="FullRow"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (Controls:DataGridRowHelper.SelectionUnit), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="FullRow"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.DisabledHighlightBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid.DisabledHighlightBrush}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Ага, хотел то же самое предложить.

Comment: @VladD, Я сначала хотел сделать `BasedOn` для нового стиля, но почему-то не сработало. Прикольно что VS15 позволяет в пару кликов получать готовые стили контролов :)

Comment: `BasedOn` тоже сработало бы по идее, вопрос только в том, на чём нужно базироваться.

Comment: @VladD, Пробовал вот так `<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">` но эффекта не было.

Comment: Возможно, `DataGrid` как-то перекрывает стиль или его части, вот наследование и не работает. В любом случае, хорошо, что сработало как у вас в ответе. Возможно, имеет смысл для будущих читателей написать, как легко получить существующий стиль (этого многие не знают, а это важно).